# ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[key] not accessible within class library

Tags: c#, azure

I am unable to access `CloudfigurationManager` from within an method. The code was originally a klass library and I added a configuration file (`App.config`) where I am simply adding the values for a hard coded test for Azure SDK.

**OpenSessionWithAzure()**

```
 private void OpenSessionWithAzure()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["APP_SETTINGS"])// Visual Studio is unable to identify ConfigurationManager
    }
```

**App.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
 <connectionStrings>
   <add name="StorageConnectionString"   connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=userName;AccountKey=Key"/>
   <add name="SasPolicyName" connectionString="myPolicy"/>   
 </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Is there a reason why I am unable to access the `ConfigurationManager` within my application or a known workaround?

Comment: Do you have reference to `System.Configuration` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this error was due to the fact that I did not:

1. Have a reference to `System.Configuration.dll` in my class library.
2. Did not have the `using System.Configuration`

After adding performing the steps above I am not able to access `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APP_SETTINGS"]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add reference to `System.Configuration` and then add key-value pair in `appSettings` section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
          <add key="SasPolicyName" value="myPolicy" />
          <add key="APP_SETTINGS" value="MySetting" />
   </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
          <add name="StorageConnectionString"   connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=userName;AccountKey=Key"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Then use like below,

```
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["APP_SETTINGS"])
```

Answer (score 1):

The method signature you use must be consistent with the setting in your `App.config`.

With the setting below,

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="StorageConnectionString" value="XXXXXXXXX"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]`.

And `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"]` for

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name ="StorageConnectionString" connectionString="XXXXXXXXXX"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you attempt to read from `appSettings`, it reads from the .config file of the executing application. So in the simplest implementation you'd just need to add those configuration settings to that application's .config file (app.config or web.config.) There are other ways to approach it if you absolutely need the library to have its own .config file, but adding it to the executing application's .config is what's done most commonly.